# SSH Persistent Connection Timeout

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I setup an ssh tunnel using a bash script, and the ssh tunnel is configured as a shared persistent connection tunnel.

At the end of my script, though, I have it setup to invoke a close command against the tunnel and to delete the .ssh/config file so that it doesn't remain open and nor does subsequent ssh tunnels that are manually started by a user.

Question is this... what is the best way to handle this issue of making sure the tunnel is closed in case someone ctrl+c the script or it crashes for some reason in the middle of the script before it invokes the close command and deletes the config file?  I was going to add a timeout to the control master, but I cannot determine what I need to use based on my readings in the ssh_config man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

on_sigint(){
    echo this function is called on ctrl+c        
}

trap "on_sigint" SIGINT SIGTERM
echo start

# Do what you want
...

echo stop
```